# Go: Best way to get time in format of YYYYMMWDDHHMMSS

Tags: time, go

I have a PHP API that takes time in format of YYYYMMWDDHHMMSS. Here W is weekday(Sunday=0, Monday = 1 ...). I am trying to generate the it like following:

```
package main

import "fmt"
import "time"

func main() {
    fmt.Println("Hello, playground")
    t := time.Now()
    time := t.Format("20060102030405")
    fmt.Println(time)
}
```

http://play.golang.org/p/Tdamoxi3bE

But it does not have weekday in it and i couldn't find any format to get from time.Format.
Is there any way to get the desired result from time.Format() or any other go 
api.

Comment: BTW, you probably want to use 15 for HH to get a 24 hour clock (3PM=15).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
package main

import "fmt"
import "strconv"
import "time"

func main() {
    fmt.Println("Hello, playground")
    t := time.Now()
    time := t.Format("20060102030405")
    time = time[:6] + strconv.Itoa(int(t.Weekday())) + time[6:]
    fmt.Println(time)
}
```

Try it on the <kbd>[Go playground](https://play.golang.org/p/d_5Zv0CyFI)</kbd>